# keep/slice specific columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I know about these column slice methods:

`df2 = df[["col1", "col2", "col3"]]` and `df2 = df.ix[:,0:2]`

but I'm wondering if there is a way to slice columns from the front/middle/end of a dataframe in the same slice without specifically listing each one.

For example, a dataframe `df` with columns: col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 and col6.

Is there a way to do something like this?

`df2 = df.ix[:, [0:2, "col5"]]`

I'm in the situation where I have hundreds of columns and routinely need to slice specific ones for different requests.  I've checked through the documentation and haven't seen something like this.  Have I overlooked something?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

IIUC, the simplest way I can think of would be something like this:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 10))
>>> df[list(df.columns[:2]) + [7]]
          0         1         7
0  0.210139  0.533249  1.780426
1  0.382136  0.083999 -0.392809
2 -0.237868  0.493646 -1.208330
3  1.242077 -0.781558  2.369851
4  1.910740 -0.643370  0.982876
```

where the `list` call isn't optional because otherwise the `Index` object will try to vector-add itself to the 7.

It would be possible to special-case something like numpy's `r_` so that

```
df[col_[:2, "col5", 3:6]]
```

would work, although I don't know if it would be worth the trouble.

Answer (score 5):

If your column names have information that you can filter for, you could use df.filter(regex='name*').
I am using this to filter between my 189 data channels from a1_01 to b3_21 and it works fine.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure exactly what you're asking. If you want the first and last 5 rows of a specific column, you can do something like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': np.random.randint(0,3,1000),
               'col2': np.random.rand(1000),
               'col5': np.random.rand(1000)}) 
In [36]: df['col5']
Out[36]: 
0     0.566218
1     0.305987
2     0.852257
3     0.932764
4     0.185677
...
996    0.268700
997    0.036250
998    0.470009
999    0.361089
Name: col5, Length: 1000 
In [38]: df['col5'][(df.index < 5) | (df.index > (len(df) - 5))]
Out[38]: 
0      0.566218
1      0.305987
2      0.852257
3      0.932764
4      0.185677
996    0.268700
997    0.036250
998    0.470009
999    0.361089
Name: col5
```

Or, more generally, you could write a function

```
In [41]: def head_and_tail(df, n=5):
    ...:     return df[(df.index < n) | (df.index > (len(df) - n))] 
In [44]: head_and_tail(df, 7)
Out[44]: 
     col1      col2      col5
0       0  0.489944  0.566218
1       1  0.639213  0.305987
2       1  0.000690  0.852257
3       2  0.620568  0.932764
4       0  0.310816  0.185677
5       0  0.930496  0.678504
6       2  0.165250  0.440811
994     2  0.842181  0.636472
995     0  0.899453  0.830839
996     0  0.418264  0.268700
997     0  0.228304  0.036250
998     2  0.031277  0.470009
999     1  0.542502  0.361089
```

Comment: What I'm looking for is a way to "keep" specific columns in a dataframe and exclude the rest.  The method you suggested is good for selecting first and last **rows** of a dataframe for any given columns, however what I'm after is a way to keep/drop columns using combined ranges/lists of columns in a slice.

Comment: So instead of what I included (first 5 and last 5 rows), you want a way to *exclude* those rows? Could you give a concrete example with a small dataframe that shows the subsets you're interested in?