# Keep specific columns from a dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe from an import csv using pandas. This dataframe has 160 variables and I would like to keep only 5, 9, 10, 46, 89.

I try this:

```
dataf2 = dataf[[5] + [9] + [10] + [46] + [89]]
```

but I take this error:

```
KeyError: '[ 5 9 10 46 89] not in index'
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data, maybe `df.head`?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh the dataset is to big unfortunately. I tried to use this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/15073977/8943781 and lets say from this solution I want to keep 1 5 7 columns

Answer (score 5):

If you want to refer to columns not by their names but by their positions in the dataset, you need to use [df.iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html#pandas.DataFrame.iloc):

```
dataf.iloc[:, [5, 9, 10, 46, 89]]
```

Row indices are specified before the comma, column indices are specified after the comma.

Answer (score 3):

If the columns that you would like to keep are: `5, 9, 10, 46, 89`, then you can index just these ones like so:

```
dataf2 = dataf[[5, 9, 10, 46, 89]]
```